# Question about construction with ruler and compass

Tags: plane-geometry, geometric-construction

Given a circunference $C$ and a line $l$, how can I find a point $A \in l$ such that the tangent lines to the circunference passing through $A$ form an given angle $\beta$?

I don't want the answer, just a tip because I'm stuck into this problem. Thanks!

Comment: I doubt that it's possible to construct arbitrary angle $\beta$ with a ruler and a compass

Comment: $\beta$ depends on $d$, distance of line from center of circle (radius $r$). $\beta \in (0, 2\sin^{-1} (r/d)]$

Comment: To expand on Vasya's comment, if this were possible without being given the angle $\beta$ first (not its measure, but two rays actually forming an angle), you could use it to construct an angle of $20^\circ$ with compass and straight-edge alone. But famously, [this is known to be impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection#Proof_of_impossibility).  On the other hand it might be possible if you are given such an angle $\beta$ first.